# Is the numerical resolution of this huge sparse polynomial system tractable?

Tags: numerical-analysis, complexity, numpy, polynomials

I'd like to find *numerically* a solution to a sparse system of 2000000 polynomial equations of degree 3 with 50000 variables and integer coefficients (or at least to decide whether or not a solution exists).

*Question*: Is there an algorithm and a supercomputer for which this computation is tractable today?

Comment: Not strictly speaking my field, but my money is on **No** (or *maybe* if you work for the NSA).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: *roughly speaking*, what is your estimate for the (space and time) complexity of this computation (and for the capacity of the *NSA supercomputers*)?

Comment: It's hard to tell. AFAIK, methods based on Gröbner bases are highly dependent on the specific structure of the equations that you are trying to solve, and the worst-case bounds are astronomically high (exponential or worse). In addition, you can construct a system of equations of the form $x_{i+1}=x_i^3$ for which the number of digits in the solution grows with the dimension, and I don't have particular reasons to believe that the decision problem is easier (apart from obvious loopholes such as "it has no solution modulo 4").

Comment: ...and let me add that the general problem of solving diophantine equations is not even [algorithmically decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_tenth_problem). So the best you can hope for is a ternary algorithm that returns yes/no/I don't know.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: *algebraically* it is certainly intractable today, but *numerically* it is not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry - my last remark applies only to *integer* solutions; I misread your question. With approximate real solutions it's a different problem.